# Firefox always scroll on hovered div

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, scroll

I'm using some overscroll-auto containers in an overflowing body. When the user is scrolling with the mousewheel, all containers should scroll to the end - working perfectly fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Sometimes Firefox skips a container and body is scrolling (instead of the div).

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogavLp - try scrolling quickly in FF an Chrome.

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.container div {
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px inset blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Any ideas on how to "force" Firefox to scroll the divs?

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with Firefox... Can't find a fix for it though...
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/904469

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Scrolling is working perfectly fine - it just takes a bit to "attach" to the div hovered on. If I leave the mouse on the div for a second, scrolling is working fine...

Comment: It seems as if Firefox moves the focus from the first scrolling div to its parent (body) document on scroll and will only focus again on another child div as soon as the mouse moves/hover occurs (you can easily see the difference when scrolling with mousewheel one time without moving the mouse and another time while moving). You may try to re-set the focus periodically using JS (but I couldn't find a code snippet for this right now).